# Xamarin Android Service Crash

Tags: android, xamarin, crash

Does anyone know what this crash dump means?

Im getting it when the app starts from a reboot **BroadcastReceiver** of the phone. It does not crash if its started from the app itself(app activity)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3399)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1780)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1538)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1484)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:663)
  at md5922925ce4b86bef9f24d805446f8ebdd.BootReceiver.n_onReceive (Native Method)
  at md5922925ce4b86bef9f24d805446f8ebdd.BootReceiver.onReceive (BootReceiver.java:29)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3392)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for Android **Oreo**, this error will pop up if you try to use **startService** at specific moments(bootup seems to be one of those moments), and to fix this I had to use **StartForegroundService** instead.
Not sure if this is the best way to do it but since my service is suppose to be a foreground one it does not hinder me.

Info to where I found it is [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes)